# How do I iterate through a matrix and retrieve the previous column in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm very new to MATLAB and not sure about this. I've a matrix

```
matrix = [1 2 3 4;8 9 5 6];
```

Now I want to iterate through the columns of the above matrix and retrieve the column 
previous to the current one. So if while iterating, we're at column 2 then we should retrieve  column 1.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I tried

```
for v = matrix 
 disp(v-1) 
end
```

but that didn't work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do note that matlab matrix operations are NOT optimized for iterating through matrices like this; they assume you're doing matrix operations on the entire matrix. Check out [this](http://www.caspur.it/risorse/softappl/doc/matlab_help/techdoc/matlab_prog/ch8_pr18.html#30189) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1109.html) on vectorizing your code.

Comment: Actually, Matlab stores matrices by columns. So it is very efficient to iterate over the columns of a matrix. It is less efficient to iterate over the rows.

Answer (score 4):

First, we need to find how many columns there are in your matrix:

```
m = [1,2,3,4;9,8,5,6]
[rows, cols] = size(m)
```

Next, we'll cycle through all the columns and print out current column:

```
for ii=1:1:cols
   disp('current column: ')
   m(:,ii) % the : selects all rows, and ii selects which column
end
```

If you wanted the previous column, rather than the current column:

```
for ii=1:1:cols
   if ii == 1
      disp('first column has no previous!')
   else
       disp('previous column: ')
       m(:,ii-1) % the : selects all rows, and ii selects columns
   end
end
```